# Show $d'(x, y)=d(x, y)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\min\{2^{-n-1}, |\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}|\}$ is a metric compatible with $d$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**The Problem**: Let $d$ be a complete metric on $X$, let $Y=\cap_n U_n$, with each $U_n$ open in $X$. Let $F_n=X-U_n$. Show that $$d'(x, y)=d(x, y)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\min\left\{2^{-n-1}, \left|\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}\right|\right\}$$ is a metric compatible with the topology on $Y$.

**Source**: *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Alexander Kechris.

**My Attempt**: To show that $d'$ is compatible with $d$, I first need to show that $d'$ is indeed a metric. As expected, the triangle inequality is the sticking point. Naturally, I wish to show that $$\min\{2^{-n-1}, |\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|\}\leq\min\{2^{-n-1}, |\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}|\}+\min\{2^{-n-1}, |\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|\}$$ for each $n$.
But I failed to even show that $$|\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|\leq |\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}|+|\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|$$, which is only one of the cases.

**Claim**: $|\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|\leq |\frac{1}{d(x, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}|+|\frac{1}{d(y, F_n)}-\frac{1}{d(z, F_n)}|$.

**Proof**: It suffices to show that $$|d(y, F_n)d(z, F_n)-d(x, F_n)d(y, F_n)|\leq|d(y, F_n)d(z, F_n)-d(x, F_n)d(z, F_n)|+|d(x, F_n)d(z, F_n)-d(x, F_n)d(y, F_n)|\quad\quad (*)$$.

The LHS of $(*)$ is $d(y, F_n)|d(x, F_n)-d(z, F_n)|$. WLOG, suppose $d(x, y)\leq1 \forall x, y\in Y$. Then $d(y, F_n)|d(x, F_n)-d(z, F_n)|\leq|d(x, F_n)-d(z, F_n)|\leq d(x, z)$ (because $|d(x, F_n)-d(y, F_n)|\leq d(x, y)\forall x, y\in Y$). **Screeching halt**. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t = \frac1{d\left(x, F_n\right)}$, $u = \frac1{d\left(y, F_n\right)}$ and $s = \frac1{d\left(z, F_n\right)}$. You want to prove that $$\min\left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |t-s|\right\} \le \min \left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |t-u|\right\} + \min \left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |u-s|\right\}$$

- If $|t-u|\le \frac1{2^{n+1}}$ and $|u-s|\le \frac1{2^{n+1}}$ then,

$$\min\left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |t-s|\right\} \le |t-s| \le |t-u| + |u-s|.$$

- If $|t-u|> \frac1{2^{n+1}}$ and $|u-s|> \frac1{2^{n+1}}$

$$\min\left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |t-s|\right\} \le \frac1{2^{n+1}} \le \frac1{2^{n+1}} + \frac1{2^{n+1}}.$$

- If $|t-u|\le \frac1{2^{n+1}}$ and $|u-s|> \frac1{2^{n+1}}$ then, $$\min\left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, |t-s|\right\} \le \frac1{2^{n+1}} \le |t-u| + \frac1{2^{n+1}}.$$

This finishes the proof of triangle inequality.

---

For the second part of the question let $\left(y_m\right)$ a convergent sequence of elements of $Y$ to $y\in Y$ with respect to $d$ and prove that $$d'\left(x_m, x\right)\to 0$$

Since $u \mapsto d\left(u, F_n\right)$ is continuous with respect to $d$ then $$\lim_{m\to \infty} d\left(y_m, F_n\right) = d\left(y, F_n\right)$$ and $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \min \left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \left|\frac1{d\left(y_m, F_n\right)}-\frac1{d\left(y, F_n\right)}\right|\right\} = 0$$

By Dominance convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \min \left\{\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \left|\frac1{d\left(y_m, F_n\right)}-\frac1{d\left(y, F_n\right)}\right|\right\} = 0$$

Comment: If you could: what is the Dominance Convergence Theorem?

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dominated_convergence_theorem it allows you to pass the limit through the sum.